# Change the database name for EntityModel

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

We have entity model objects created using a database named 'A' and  now moved the database to new server with the name 'B'..So we changed the connection string in the config file and tried to connect database 'B' but getting exception like 'A.dbo.[table]' not found..

If we change the database name do we need to recreate the models even though there is no difference between the databases except the name..

Comment: Without more information, I would suggest you inspect the databases again. Are you sure the two databases (A & B) are identical? Also, in the database, inspect any triggers, views or procedures that may be  referencing the old db name. Hope that helps.

Comment: Both databases are identical..And we are getting exception which says "Invalid object name 'A.dbo.[TableName]'"..I am not sure from where it is picking up the old database name 'A'..

Comment: Any triggers, views or stored procedures in db ? If so, inspect those .

Comment: Also, you can run SQL profiler to isolate

Comment: I am reviewing each object and trying to see if we have the database name used anywhere..Thank you so much..

Comment: Can you give the entire exception ?

Comment: I found the problem, because we have tons of stored procs and some of them using fully qualified names for tables like A.dbo.[TableName]..Hope changing all of them will fix the problem..

Comment: Ah, so yes, as I stated, inspect stored procedures, views and triggers...perhaps even functions

Comment: Sure, Thanks again for pointing me in right direction.. :)

Comment: Np. Had similar issues in the past after promoting the environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121392/discussion-between-ryancji-and-classic-vmk).

Answer (score 0):

If the tables aren't found then you need to run the migrations. You can either enable automatic migrations within the DBContext, or run

```
update-database
```

from the Package Manager console in Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi we took back up of database 'A' and restored in our new server..So the database 'B' is similar to database 'A' but just the name is different..

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding this properly. You had a database A on database server A_S. You have renamed database A to database B and restored a backup of database A on a new database server B_S while making sure to change the name of A to B while restoring?

Comment: Sorry If I confused you :) --- I had database A on server A_S.Restored the A in server B_S with database name as B.

Comment: Ah, that should work just fine. I'd double check if there is another connection string you missed somewhere. The fact that the application is still calling out Database A makes me think an old connection string is hiding someplace.

Comment: I am sure we don't have another connection string, we are getting this error because it is using the updated connectionstring...